# How to find out actual height of div?

Tags: html, css, firefox-developer-tools

I have a div that I am setting the width and height of to fixed values because I would like to add a vertical scroll to it only if and when its content overflows its size.

Here's what I have done:

**Site.html**

```css
element {
}
#foo {
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.verticalScrollIfNeeded {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.hasContentToItsRight {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id = "foo" class = "verticalScrollIfNeeded">
      Foo bar har zar dar mar gar har par yar lar nar
    </div>
```

**Site.css**

```
.verticalScrollIfNeeded
{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#foo
{
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

However, no matter how much content I put into it, it just keeps growing in height. Also, its actual width and height are much more than the max-width and max-height I have set in the CSS.

**My question(s) are:**

1. How do I get it to have a fixed height and width with a vertical scroll only when its content exceeds its size?

AND

2. How do I get the actual width and height of a div at a point in time using the developer tools in most modern browsers today. I am using Firefox 43.0.4 most of the time.

**UPDATED:**
Here are all the CSS rules it has applied to itself, whether directly or in the form of inherited ones:

```
element {
}
#foo {
    max-width: 180px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.verticalScrollIfNeeded {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.hasContentToItsRight {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**FINAL UPDATE AND RESOLVED**

Really sorry for wasting all of your time. The fault was mine. Though in this example, I had taken a `div` with the id `foo`, in my code, I had a `span` that I was applying all this to. I have a faint recollection about some controls, span being one of them, not following the `box` rules or some such. Whatever that was, in summary, I turned my span into a `div` and all the world fell into its proper place.

Comment: It keeps growing? Like an animation?

Comment: No. I mean every time I edit the content in the control and post back, the next time I retrieve the page, the control's height has grown to accommodate all of the content.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwVZXv - the max-height is honoured

Comment: Press F12 or right click on an element you're interested in and select inspect element from the context menu. On the right in Firefox there's a tab called box model, click that. In chrome, click on computed. In IE click on Layout. In Chrome, when you hover over an element with F12, it shows you the size on screen.

Comment: @gaynorvader Thanks. Then I've been doing it right because I've been reading the actual width and height of the box from the *Box Model* tab in Firefox Developer Tools and the values are much higher than those I set as the `max-height` and `max-width`.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 go to styles and make sure your `max-width` and `max-height` are not being overwritten by any other rules.

Comment: @gaynorvader Thank you. I had actually looked at those before I posted the question and couldn't find anything that I know of could be the reason. I have updated the question to include all the styles including the inherited ones.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I get it to have a fixed height and width with a vertical
>   scroll only when its content exceeds its size?

By using `overflow: auto` and `max-height`. Your code already works.

```css
.verticalScrollIfNeeded {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#foo {
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="verticalScrollIfNeeded">
  Foo<br />bar<br />har<br />zar<br />dar<br />mar<br />gar<br />har<br />par<br />yar<br />lar<br />nar
</div>
```

> How do I get the actual width and height of a div at a point in time
>   using the developer tools in most modern browsers today. I am using
>   Firefox 43.0.4 most of the time.

1. Open developer tools
2. Go to Inspector tab
3. Choose the desired element
4. Go to Box Model subpanel

You will see the sizes, paddings, borders and margins.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That means I did it right. I had seen the values in this place and verified that the width and height displayed in the *Box Model* were much higher than the values I had set for `max-width` and `max-height`.

Comment: Then go to the Rules subpanel to see which rules apply.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 This shouldn't be possible. Please include a reproducible demo in your question.

Comment: It was my fault. I found the cause of the bug and have updated the question. Sorry about all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the culprit.

I looked up the CSS related errors in the console, and out of a dozen of them or so was one that read such:

```
Unknown property 'overflow-wrap'.  Declaration dropped.
```

I think I know what to do now.

Comment: This means `overflow-wrap: break-word` is ignored. Other styles should still apply.

Comment: You're probably right. Still testing out my changes and trying to find the cause of the bug.